# Authenticate multiple Azure Powershell Functions

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

I have built a few Powershell functions using Azure Functions, and it is working like a charm.

Now that I have proven the concept I would very much like to refactor my existing functions.

First of all I would like to move the authentication required in my function to some kind of shared function or whatever.

Here is my example function, which return a list of all web apps in my resource group.

```
# Authenticate with subscription
$subscriptionId = "<SubscriptionId>"
$resourceGroupName = "<ResourceGroupName>";
$tenantId = "<TenantId>"
$applicationId = "<ApplicationId>"
$password = "<Password>"
$userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$userCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $applicationId, $userPassword
Add-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $tenantid -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -Credential $userCredential
Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionId $subscriptionId | Select-AzureRmSubscription

# Get all web apps
$Websites = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$Websites = $Websites | select name | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

# Write output
Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject $Websites
```

I would very much like to move everything from line 1 to line 10 somewhere else. Is it possible? If yes, can anyone please point me in the right direction here?

---

**Update**

Thanks to both Walter and Pragna I combined the two methods like this.

**run.ps1**

```
# Authenticate with subscription
Import-Module 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Authentication.ps1'

# Get all web apps
$Websites = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $env:ResourceGroupName
$Websites = $Websites | select name | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

# Write output
Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject $Websites
```

**Authentication.ps1**

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $env:Password -AsPlainText -Force;
$userCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($env:ApplicationId, $secpasswd)
Add-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $env:TenantId -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionId $env:SubscriptionId -Credential $userCredential
Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionId $env:SubscriptionId | Select-AzureRmSubscription
```

Comment: probably precompiled functions might help you, never tried that with powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unsafe for you to save your account information in script. I suggest you could store these to `App Setting`. You could find it `Your function app-->Settings-->Application settings-->Manage application settings-->App settings` and  key-value pairs for the settings SP_USERNAME, SP_PASSWORD, and TENANTID, SubscriptionId(You also could use other values or more key pairs).
[image]

Modify your script as below:

```
# Set Service Principal credentials
    # SP_PASSWORD, SP_USERNAME, TENANTID are app settings
    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $env:SP_PASSWORD -AsPlainText -Force;
    $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($env:SP_USERNAME, $secpasswd)
    Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $env:TENANTID -Credential $mycreds;
    Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionId $env:subscriptionId | Select-AzureRmSubscription
```

When you want to modify your account information, you don't need modify your script, you only need modify app setting. You could modify app setting by using Azure CLI.

Comment: Perfect! It works, I was looking for something like this, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can import custom powershell modules.

- Create a shared directory e.g. bin under D:\home\site\wwwroot
- Copy module to the shared directory
- Call Import-Module SharedDir\MyModule.psm1 or SharedDir\MyScript.ps1 or SharedDir\MyModule.psd1 or SharedDir\MyLib.dll

Also, here is a [sample](https://blog.tyang.org/2016/10/07/using-custom-powershell-modules-in-azure-functions/) that might help.

Comment: Thanks! I combined your answer with Walters :)